# Open a file in default viewer from package/res folder

Tags: java

i'm building this game. Now at the main screen when HELP is clicked i want view an image or a PDF file in the operating systems default viewer. The file well be in my "package/res" folder along with other files. How can i do that? Please check the image in the link. I'll provide further information if needed.

[enter link description here](http://s21.postimg.org/58qykyvhz/Screen_Shot_2014_12_22_at_2_42_29_AM.png)

Comment: I tried with "File f = new File("");" but it needs a specific address so it can't be loaded in other pc's. I want to open a file from my applications "res" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find registered apps to open a file otherwise it will throw error. So also write how to handle those errors.

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            File myFile = new File("path");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: How can set the path to my "application/res" folder so that it runs on all computers. If here i say the path is C:/... then on any other pc's i have to copy the file to that pc's C: drive.

Comment: create a folder inside your project(ex:- res) and add those files and path would be res/file.pdf

Comment: 'File f = new File("res\background.png");
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
dt.open(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}'

I did this but gives error.